# Add dynamic row in between table

Tags: angular, tabular

I am facing issue while trying to add one row in between table.

[image]

As visible in image there are 3 rows, and history button for 2 rows. All I need to show details on history button click, but it should be just after the button's row. Right now when I am trying to do toggle or show/hide it is going to after the last row only.

**I am trying to do it in angular4**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution

I have create a demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-dynamic-row-in-between-table?file=src/app/app.component.html) . I hope this will help/guide to you/others.

> html code

```
 <table width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Birth Date</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let customtable of customTable" style="vertical-align: top;">
            <td>{{customtable.name}}</td>
            <td>{{customtable.gender}}</td>
            <td>{{customtable.birth | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
            <td>{{customtable.city}}</td>
            <td>{{customtable.state}}</td>
            <td>{{customtable.country}}</td>
            <td>
                <tr *ngFor="let act of customtable.actions">
                    <button >{{act.text}}</button>
                </tr>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

> ts file code

```
customTable = [{
    name: 'User 1',
    gender: 'Male',
    birth: new Date(),
    city: 'Indore',
    state: 'MP',
    country: 'India',
    actions: [{
      id: 1,
      text: 'undo last step'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      text: 'history'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      text: 'extra'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'User 2',
    gender: 'Female',
    birth: new Date(),
    city: 'Ahmedabad',
    state: 'Gujarat',
    country: 'India',
    actions: [{
      id: 1,
      text: 'Review patient'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      text: 'extra'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'User 1',
    gender: 'Male',
    birth: new Date(),
    city: 'Indore',
    state: 'MP',
    country: 'India',
    actions: [{
      id: 1,
      text: 'undo last step'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      text: 'history'
    }]
  }]
```

Comment: Thanks Krishna, But you have created html view only, buttons are not clickable. All i need is to click on history button and add one row after history button's row.

Comment: I am not understand your mean. verify in detail

Comment: you can try 
 <tr *ngFor="let act of customtable.actions">
    <button (click)="btnClick()">{{act.text}}</button>
</tr>